# Create def Check if a URL is Vaild if it is not found go to a different URL to edit that field but check the current URL then pull the correct info

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python-3.7

Trying To create def Check if a URL is Valid if it is not found go to a different URL pressed a button to edit that field but check the current URL then pull the correct info from config and send to the text field
below is what I am looking at

```
<tbody><tr>
                    <th width="150">License Key *</th>
                    <td width="1">:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="LicenseKey" value="" size="80" maxlength="64"></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
```

>

```
def licenses(value):
    try:
        gotoURL(builder+value)
        if driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main-message"]/h1/span'):
            gotoURL(base_url+value)
        if driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main-message"]/h1/span'):
            gotoURL(server1+value)
        if driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main-message"]/h1/span'):
            gotoURL(server2+value)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pressButton(license_edit)
        if driver.current_url(builder):
            sendKeys(license_key,server_license)
        if driver.current_url(base_url):
            sendKeys(license_key,serverlicense)
        if driver.current_url(zach_server):
            sendKeys(license_key,server_license1)
        if driver.current_url(michael_server):
            sendKeys(license_key,server_license2)
```

this is the errors I am getting TypeError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that you are getting the typeError because

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath()
```

returns a WebElement that for whatever reason can’t be converted to a boolean for your if statements. Try switching to

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath()
```

This method will still work even if only one element is found, it just returns an array containing that element.  This is important because python is able to see an array of length 1+ (if one or more elements are found) and convert it to a Boolean as true.